# I have a doulbt about jwt token

Tags: node.js, node-modules, package.json

I have a doulbt about jwt token.
When I create a token, I need pass the payload the secret and the expiresIn to the method jwt.sign from jsonwebtoken package. In metters of security what  the secret do to protect the token once I can get this same token in my frontend and decode this token whitout pass the secret phrase to get all payload informations using the jwt-decode in my frontend in reactjs. In addition I can get this same token and decode it into the jwt.io to get all information from this same token so what is the utily of the secret phrase when I create the token in my backend.

Understanding the necessity of using jwt secret

Comment: Yes, you can decode jwt payload. Its a base64 encoded string. But you need to have the secret to verify the token and sign the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly dont share the secret used to generate the token, usually the signing application will generate a unique secret when it loads for the lifecycle of the application.

You are correct that you can decode a token, when you use JWT.io you can see the **claims** of the token, that is expected and really important actually.

The key to token security is the last part of the token called the sig or signiture, this is all of the claims of the token encrypted using the secret.

A token is therefore considered valid if:

1. Expiry is within time set in token claims (expires at param usually)
2. The signiture, when decrypted using the secret, matches all of the claims

So provided the secret is kept secret, the token is considered secure. of course if someone steals a token it can be reused so keep it safe.

Also for reason above, keep expiry as short as reasonably possible, then if you token is stolen it will only be valid for a short period of time.

Look at [this](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/) resource for more info